# Ubuntu 14.04 loosing links for windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, shortcuts

I have ubuntu 14.04 and windows 10 on my laptop, dual boot.
And I made some shortcuts on ubuntu for some places on partition where is widows. And it works correctly until i restart my laptop, after that, when I try to use these links, It popup text: 
"This link cannot be used because its target “/media/maksim/BECCBAE3CCBA94DD1/Users/Maksim/Desktop” doesn't exist."

Comment: You need to set permanent mounts for Windows partitions in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set permanent mount point for your windows-partition! otherwise this is like looking for a file on a usb-stick without attaching it...! :-/

---

to achieve this first you have to identify the right (windows-)partition:
open a terminal, type `sudo blkid` and you should get a list with all your partitions like this:

```
user@computer ~ $ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Root" UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="windows" UUID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ntfs"
```

there may be more entries but if you labeled your partitions it wont be hard. copy the UUID of the desired partition for the next step.

then type `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and simply add the following line:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   /mnt/windows    ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8   0   0
```

pay attention to the following:

- between every of the 6 entries use 1 tab stop, not spaces. - and don't use spaces within the blocks!
- the UUID is the one you looked for, BUT without the quotes.
- with `/mnt/your_destination` the windows-drive won't show up in the file manager like external drives.
- if you have to use a mount point (`/mnt/your_destination`) with spaces use quotes (`/mnt/"your destination"`).

save the file and close gedit.

the last step is to create the chosen mount point:
type `sudo mkdir /mnt/your_destination` and you are ready to go.

restart the computer or just type `sudo mount -a` and it will work.

Comment: if it is to hard for you to find the correct partition with `sudo blkid` maybe use `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l` to identify the right one... or simply use `/dev/sdX0` as identification.